# Marionette ItemView Event on image loaded

Tags: jquery, marionette, jquery-events, backbone-views

I'm looking for a way to trigger some code once an image has been completely rendered within the browser.  I am using isotopes masonry http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ plugin that uses the height of the element to calculate the Masonry layout, but unfortunately the `onShow` and `onRender` events fire too early, before the image has fully loaded and rendered and therefore the wrong height is being calculated by isotope. I tried using https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded to help solve the issue, but the code is still firing too early.  Any suggestions how I can ask the ItemView to wait until the image is fully displayed within the DOM?

```
List.Recipe = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#recipe-list-item',
    model: this.model,
    className: 'isotope--recipe',
    serializeData: function () {
      var data = this.model.toJSON()
      return data
    },
    onShow: function () {
      $(this).imagesLoaded().done( function () {
        $('.isotope--recipes').isotope({
          itemSelector: ".isotope--recipe",
          masonry: {
            gutter: 25
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
```

I've also tried

```
List.Recipe = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#recipe-list-item',
    model: this.model,
    className: 'isotope--recipe',
    serializeData: function () {
      var data = this.model.toJSON()
     return data
    },
    initialize: function () {
      Marionette.bindEntityEvents(this, this, this.events)
    },
    triggers: {
      'load img': 'image:loaded'
    },
    events: {
      'image:loaded': 'masonryise'
    },
    masonryise: function () {
      $('.isotope--recipes').isotope({
      itemSelector: ".isotope--recipe",
      masonry: {
       gutter: 25
      }
  })
}
})
```

Comment: Why don't you set a hard height and width size to the element instead of waiting for the image to be loaded. That way you know what sizes it is beforehand. I personally use CSS for images on a div because I can stretch it or fill the container and center.

Comment: Hi Yes that's what I did but it then requires me to unset it later so that I can allow for the window to be resized if the user wants and for the elements to be able to respond to that event.

Answer (score 0):

It appears load events don't work as expected in the events hash as [suggested here](https://gitter.im/marionettejs/backbone.marionette?at=57d1678dcdbf820f7fa89b3d), so you can connect these using addEventListener something like this:

```
layout: function (container) {
    var that = this;
    if (that.layoutComplete) {
        return;
    }
    if (!that.msnry) {
        that.msnry = new Masonry(container,
            {
                gutter: 10,
                itemSelector: '.item'
            });
    }

    if (!that.images) {
        that.images = Array.from(that.el.querySelectorAll(".masonry img"));
        //load events don't seem to fire from the events hash so connect them manually
        that.images.forEach((i) => i.addEventListener("load",
            function(evt) {
                that.layout();
            }));
    }

    if (that.images.every(function (img) { return img.complete; })) {
        that.layoutComplete = true;
        //final layout once all finished
        that.msnry.layout();
    } else if (!that.firstLayoutComplete && that.images.slice(0, 10).every(function (img) { return img.complete; })) {
        that.firstLayoutComplete = true;
        //layout once first 10 are loaded to appear responsive
        that.msnry.layout();
    }
},

onShow: function () {
    var container = this.el.querySelector('.masonry>div');

    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        this.layout(container);
    } else {
        jQuery(window).on("load", function () {
            this.layout(container);
        });
    }

}
```